# Optimize: value replacement in data frame wiith multiple conditions

Tags: r, optimization

I have a data frame similar to this sample:

```
df <- structure(list(Ball = structure(c(5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("blue", "blue is my favourite", "red", "red ", "red ball"), class = "factor"), size = c(1.2, 2, 3, 10, 12, 100)), .Names = c("Ball", "size"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Based on the information in the two columns I want to classify the items by size and color. The output should look like this:

```
structure(list(Ball = structure(c(5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("blue", "blue is my favourite", "red", "red ", "red ball"), class = "factor"), size = c(1.2, 2, 3, 10, 12, 100), Class = c("small red ball", "small red ball", "small blue ball", "medium red ball", "medium blue ball", "big red ball")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .Names = c("Ball", "size", "Class"), class = "data.frame")
```

I have running code, but its very long and chaotic and I am sure there is a more neat way to get my desired output.

**So what did I do?**

I started with selecting the items of the first class and rename the selected `df$Class` values:

```
df["Class"] <- NA #add new column

df[grepl("red", df$Ball) & df$size <10, ]$Class <- "small red ball"
```

and because my grepl-selection is sometimes empty, I added a `if (length() > 0`) condition:

```
if (length(df[grepl("red", df$Ball) & df$size <10, ]$Class) > 0) {df[grepl("red", df$Ball) & df$size <10, ]$Class <- "small red ball"}
```

and finally I combined all my selections in a loop

```
df["Class"] <- NA #add new column
z <- c("red", "blue")

for (i in z){
  if (length(df[grepl(i, df$Ball) & df$size <10, ]$Class) > 0) {df[grepl(i, df$Ball) & df$size <10, ]$Class <- paste("small", i, "ball", sep=" ")}
  if (length(df[grepl(i, df$Ball) & df$size >=10 & df$size <100, ]$Class) > 0) {df[grepl(i, df$Ball) & df$size >=10 & df$size <100, ]$Class <- paste("medium", i, "ball", sep=" ")}
  if (length(df[grepl(i, df$Ball) & df$size >=100, ]$Class) > 0) {df[grepl(i, df$Ball) & df$size >=100, ]$Class <- paste("big", i, "ball", sep=" ")}
}
```

It works for two colors and three size categories, but my original data frame is much bigger. Therfore (and because it looks so chaotic), my question: 
**How can I simplify my code?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `cut` to create the grouping based on the 'size' and `paste` it with the extracted values of 'Ball' using `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
df$Class <- with(df, paste(as.character(cut(size, breaks = c(1, 9, 99, Inf), 
   labels = c('small', 'medium', 'big'))),  str_extract(Ball, 'red|blue'), 'ball'))
df$Class
#[1] "small red ball"   "small red ball"   "small blue ball"
#[4] "medium red ball"  "medium blue ball" "big red ball"
```

Comment: I do not see the the essence of  of the `stringr` package. I guess base r works fin:  `paste(as.character(cut(df$size,c(1,10,100,Inf), c("small","medium","large"))), 
      sub("[^(red|blue)].*","",df$Ball),'Ball')`

Comment: @Onyambu Sure the `sub` works, but if there are no matches, then it could return the whole string where as `str_extract` returns NA.  One workaround would be `regexpr/regmatches`

Comment: The breaks should be `c(1, 9, 99, Inf)` for `small: x < 10`, `medium 10 <= x < 100`, `large: x  >= 100`, right?

Comment: @Iris  Yes, sorry, I didn't check the breaks earlier.  Corrected it

Answer (score 2):

This answer is very similar to @akrun's, but you can include more colors (here's I'm using the `colors()` palette, but you can use other ones as well. I also slightly changed the arguments for the `cut` function.

```
size<- cut(df$size, c(0, 10, 100, Inf), labels = c("small", "medium", "big"), right=F)
colors<- str_extract(df$Ball, paste(colors(), collapse="|"))
df$Class<- paste(size, colors, "ball", sep = " ")

> df
                  Ball  size            Class
1             red ball   1.2   small red ball
2                  red   2.0   small red ball
3 blue is my favourite   3.0  small blue ball
4                 red   10.0  medium red ball
5                 blue  12.0 medium blue ball
6                  red 100.0     big red ball
```

Also, to make it a bit more general, you can allow for capital letters by using:

```
colors<- str_extract(df$Ball, regex(paste(colors(), collapse="|"), ignore_case=T))
```

So if `df$Ball[1] = "Red ball"`, using the line above you get:

```
colors
#[1] "Red"  "red"  "blue" "red"  "blue" "red" 
df$Class<- paste(size, tolower(colors), "ball", sep = " ")
df$Class
#[1] "small red ball"   "small red ball"   "small blue ball"  "medium red ball"  "medium blue ball"
#[6] "big red ball"
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a great case to use the `dplyr` and `stringr` packages:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(list(Ball = structure(c(5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("blue", "blue is my favourite", "red", "red ", "red ball"), class = "factor"), size = c(1.2, 2, 3, 10, 12, 100)), .Names = c("Ball", "size"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))


df %>%
  mutate(
    color = str_extract(`Ball`, "(red)|(blue)"),
    size_category = case_when(
      size < 10 ~ "small",
      size >= 10 & size < 100 ~ "medium",
      size >= 100 ~ "large"
    ),
    category = str_c(size_category, color, "ball", sep = " ")
  )
```